# How do I search for one data set in an array?

Tags: java

I have been filling each 'block' of an array with multiple pieces of data. In this case the name breed age sex and weight of a dog. How would I go about searching for a specific dog out of that array? I have the dogs ID'd via a counter, but the user is allowed to change that ID in an update, so the ID could be different than the autogenerated ID that is a counter.

Comment: You can iterate over the array to find an element. I assume you have a `Dog` class. Implement the `equals` (and `hashcode` for completeness) method for that, or create your own e.g., `isRequested` that takes the user provided ID and compares each `Dog` in your array with that.

Comment: You should show us some code, and some sample data, and explain just what you want your code to do

Comment: If you want to have an autogenerated ID you can rely on, then don't let the user change it.